# Tracking browsing pattern of website user

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I own website (typical registration and various links.Made in CAKEPHP, MYSQL).

I want to track every user browsing pattern without hurting speed of website.

I tried following DB.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER_ID      |     source_link       | destination_link   |  time_spent(second)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1              wwww.../link1       ww..///link2             300
2              link3               \link4                   160
.......
```

Then i store row in DB whenever user click to any URL.
Now am i in right direction.

If this is practical then how can i implement this. 
If not then please suggest me better way to do that.

Comment: have you tried google analytics

Comment: That information should already be in your site's access_log. There is no reason to slap on a database layer which will only hurt performance. Use a log analyzer to build the click trail AFTER the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how large your traffic is.

If you want to follow a pattern then the best way would be to use [Google Analytics funnels](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en).

If you want to process all traffic by yourself I would just process the access_log files using [Hive](https://gist.github.com/emk/1556097) or some [dedicated tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache%20log%20analyzer&oq=apache%20log%20an&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j5j69i61j0j69i61.3063j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

I would not save the traffic directly in a database (it's not cheap to scale for high traffic). Maybe you can save the traffic in a csv file on disk and insert it in mysql using a cron and the [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) syntax which is much faster.

Comment: I already using that. but now i want to see the browsing pattern for specific login user not guest user.

Comment: Here is more important section of my website like which portion of my website is good for user.I also want to create a analysis front end on my own for this.